# C socket: recv and send simultaneously

Tags: c, sockets, select, tcp, network-programming

I am trying to make a client server chat application with a single server and multiple client scenario. My server is working but I cant get the client working. I am using select() function to select whether I should recv() or send(). Here is my code for client implementation.

```
main()
{
int sockfd;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

int i, sent;
char buf[100];
char buff[100];

/*
Opening a socket 
Check whether opening is successful or not
*/
if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
    printf("Unable to create socket\n");
}
printf("Socket created\n");


serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(6000);

/*
Establish a connection with the server process
*/
if((connect(sockfd, (struct socketaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)))<0){
    printf("Unable to connect to server\n");
    exit(0);
}

printf("Client connected\n");

while(1){

    for(i=0; i<100; i++){
        buf[i] = '\0';
        buff[i] = '\0';
    }

    fd_set rfd, wfd;
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    FD_ZERO( &rfd);
    FD_ZERO( &wfd);

    FD_SET( sockfd, &rfd);
    //FD_SET( sockfd, &wfd);
    FD_SET( 0, &wfd);

    if( (select( sockfd + 1, &rfd, &wfd, NULL, &tv) < 0)) {
        printf(" Select error \n");
        exit(0);
    }

    if( FD_ISSET( sockfd, &rfd)) { // we got data ... need to read it
        recv(sockfd, buff, 100, 0);
        printf("Received result from server = %s\n",buff);
    }

    if( FD_ISSET( 0, &wfd)) {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf(">");
        gets(buf);
        sent = send(sockfd, buf, strlen(buf) + 1, 0);
        printf("-------------Sent %d bytes to server--------------\n", sent);
    }
}
printf("----------------Closing client------------------ \n");
close(sockfd);
}
```

Each client should get the message sent by one client to the server just like a chat application.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you should know that calling `fflush` in an input stream (like `stdin`) is *undefined*. Don't do it if you want your code to be portable. You should also ***never*** use `gets`, it's dangerous and have even been removed from the C standard. I also recommend you use e.g. `STDIN_FILENO` instead of the ["magic number"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) `0`.

Comment: @Joachim Thanks a lot!! Should I use `fgets` instead of `gets` ?

Comment: Yes, that's the recommended replacement. Note that `fgets` will add the newline into the buffer (if it fits), so you have to check for it and remove it (by replacing it with the string terminator character).

Comment: I think it must be stopping at third if block in while loop because of gets()... so it can not read like realtime chat application, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you check if you can *write* to the standard *input* file descriptor. That makes no sense, you should check if you can *read* from it.

That is, you should add `STDIN_FILENO` to the read set too, and not have a write set at all.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue some days ago, but in c++. My problems were solved using these links:

- http://easy-tutorials.net/c/multithreaded-socket-server-cpp/#comment-1024
- http://easy-tutorials.net/c/linux-c-socket-programming/#creating_a_server

Probably you can adapt to your situation, this socket server make a broadcast as you want. Try compile it and you will see how it is works.

If you need some help, do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Joachim Pileborg's answer solved my problem but thanks for your reply.